# How do I unzip a file?

Tags: linux, software-installation

I am new to the Raspberry Pi and I have a Pi 3. I cannot figure out how to unzip a file. I tried using Archiver, but I get an error message.

Comment: What's the error message? We are not omniscient.

Comment: @Jacobm001, well, I am!

Answer (score 5):

To unzip a file you use the unzip command:

```
unzip filename
```

You can read the documentation with the following command:

```
man unzip
```

Our most recent [blog post](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/142634263599/improving-your-command-line-skills-part-3) "Improving Your Command Line Skills Part 3" has a function that makes extracting files easier. [Part one](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/141758901139/improving-your-command-line-skills-part-1) covered man pages (the builtin documentation).

Comment: Just as I was about to link the blog...

Comment: I don't believe that unzip is installed by default. The article about [installing software](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/140986024839/installing-applications-on-a-raspberry-pi-running) may be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to unzip files from the command line. Remember to use sudo if the file is only accessible by root.

```
unzip filenamp.zip
```